# Error when execute sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, error, command-line

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/magento2/bin/../app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento on line 14

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/magento2/bin/../app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento on line 14
```

***Error when execute sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade***

Comment: Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

---

Please make sure the file `/var/www/html/magento2/app/bootstrap.php` is available.

```
No such file or directory
```

This error indicates it is not.

Also make sure to set correct permission to your files as described:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_perms.html

With `sudo` this shouldn't be a problem, nevertheless I recommend not using super user.

Answer (score 0):

Check the folders and files permissions.

Go to the core project folder and run the next commands:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc && chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml && chmod +x bin/magento
```